# How to model circular data in ios app

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, database-design

I'm trying to come up with a schema for the data that I'm trying to model but always end up with a circular reference; I must be missing something but am looking for advice on the best way model this.

Suppose I am pulling a list of photos from a web service, for every photo I want to pull out the photographer and the region that it was taken in so that I can run queries to see how many photos a photographer has, and how many photographers have taken photos in a particular region.

What is the best way to model this? I think a photo has 1 photographer and is in 1 region, but each photographer/region can have multiple photos, and a region also needs a relationship with the photographers so that we can see how many have taken photos in a particular region.

This is how I picture the relationship (hopefully diagram makes sense), but this creates a circle...

Photo*>--Photographer*>--<*Region--<*Photo

Not sure if it makes a difference but this is for an iOS app using sqlite3

Comment: You have three tables: "Photo", "Photographer" and "Region". Add foreign keys to "Photo" for "Photographer" and "Region". Then make queries to obtain the result set you need. Or just have fields for the "Photographer" and "Region" names. There are many things to consider including normalization and needs. If you are going to design your own schemas you really need to study database schema design and the SQL query language. An alternative to consider is to use CoreData.

Comment: This question is probably more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding, "and a region also needs a relationship with the photographers so that we can see how many have taken photos in a particular region."

No it doesn't.  All the region table needs is an id field and information about the region.  Also, the photographer can't have a regionId field because they can probably take photos from more than one region.  Having said that, depending on your requirements, it might have a CurrentHomeRegionID field that is a foreign key to region.

If you have a photographer_id and region_id in your photo table, you can run pretty much any query you want.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. It seems like I just need to read up more on DB design because I was thinking that if you want to get all of the photos in a region then running a query on all the photos where region is X seems inefficient compared to linking the region and photos directly.